# App/Tool to encapsulate a web page into like an independent app

Tags: software-recommendation, electron

I'm looking for functionality equivalent to Electron apps, but I want to do it myself with any web page.

There is an equivalent app for Mac, called Unite: https://www.bzgapps.com/unite

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [nativefier](https://github.com/nativefier/nativefier). It is free and open-source. It depends on Node.js, and can be installed with `npm install -g nativefier`. Full installation instructions are [on their GitHub README](https://github.com/nativefier/nativefier#installation).

The usage is pretty simple, too. Just run `nativefier "example.com"`, and it will make it into an Electron app. You can also set the name and many other things manually, if you prefer. A list of all the options are [on GitHub](https://github.com/nativefier/nativefier/blob/master/API.md).

Answer (score 0):

I've been using nativefier too, and I wanted to just add a little more instruction as to how to use it, guidance which I found through this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hFaoNuyidM).

- Make a folder where you'll want the apps to be kept in your home folder, e.g. ElectronApps.
- navigate to that folder in terminal, `cd ElectronApps`
- Assuming you're using x64 architecture, use the following to install the desired app, replacing the placeholders `nativefier --name "DesiredAppNameHere" -p linux -a x64 https://relevanturl.here`
- Make the app executable by navigating into the app folder `cd DesiredAppNameHere` and run `sudo chmod +x DesiredAppNameHere`.
- To add the app to the dashboard/launcher, you can use Main Menu. If you don't already know how to install and use that for this purpose, the same video I linked before includes guidance, but here it is again starting at the relevant [part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=554&v=-hFaoNuyidM).